# Book Recommendation For Vector Space Isomorphism Theorems

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I am teaching a one-semester course in linear algebra, **focusing on the various structure theorems concerning vector spaces. The course does not touch upon module theory.** My students have already taken a course in abstract algebra, and are comfortable with the isomorphism theorems concerning groups and rings.

I wanted to know if there are any good books that cover the correspondence theorem and the three isomorphism theorems for vector spaces that I can suggest to my students as reading material. It would be helpful if the book had some good exercises as well. It is alright if the book is fairly sophisticated in its presentation. My own first exposure to the isomorphism theorems in linear algebra was in the context of modules, so I am unable to think of a good book that does not touch the theory of modules and still covers the isomorphism theorems for vector spaces.

Please do not mention random books that you find on amazon or the internet. I can do a search of that sort myself. I am assuming the person answering this question has (at least somewhat) read the book, and is answering from the perspective of a mathematician or a mathematics student.

Thank you for any good recommendations in advance :)

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Usually linear algebra is taught at the very first semester, without quotient spaces and isomorphism theorems. Students usually learn group theory later, and that's when they usually see the isomorphism theorems for the first time. Once you learn the isomorphism theorems for groups, you immediately understand these theorems for all other algebraic structures, there is almost no difference at all. So it makes perfect sense that it's hard to find a book that will discuss isomorphism theorems for vector spaces in detail.

Comment: The third chapter from Advanced Linear Algebra by Steven Roman should do.

Comment: @Mark I am actually teaching a second course in linear algebra. My students had a semester of linear algebra already, but this second course is more focused on the structure theorems, bilinear forms and the spectral theorem, the various relations between polynomials and matrices, and basics of multilinear products. The students also have an upcoming second course in commutative algebra, so we have decided to defer a treatment of modules to that course.

Comment: @Ningxin I did think of that, and that is what I plan on using if I don't obtain much help from this question. I felt that the students might have some difficulty in studying from that book because the proofs are not written out in detail. Of course, I am going to be doing the proofs in class, but I thought it might be helpful for them if the material was presented in a more "student-friendly" manner, so to speak.

Comment: Chapter II of Greub's *Linear Algebra*, 4th edition, possibly with some supplementation of your own, could work.

Comment: @blargoner Thank you for the suggestion! That was definitely helpful.